# Is Amino Acid Supplementation Necessary When Taking Whey Protein

Tags: supplements

L-Tyrosine and Beta Alanine have Will Brink's endorsement as worthwhile supplements.

My question is: are these really necessary with protein supplementation as Tyrosine and Alanine will ultimately be derived from the protein in whey?

Answer (score 3):

Not at all. Getting your nutrients from food is a lot better than getting them isolated in supplements. Whey is about as close to food as you're going to get from a supplement. If there's an amino acid that you won't get from your food or from the whey, then it would make sense to take it as a separate supplement, but doubling up is just going to end up costing you more money without a matching benefit to show for it.

Comment: Somehow I can't match your reputation with this answer. If somebody with a reputation of say 21 said this I would definitely down-voted him and told him he doesn't know anything about supplementation.

Comment: Considering dictionary definition of Dietary Supplements as "*A dietary supplement is intended to provide nutrients that may otherwise not be consumed in sufficient quantities.

Supplements as generally understood include vitamins, minerals, fiber, fatty acids, or amino acids, among other substances. U.S. authorities define dietary supplements as foods, while elsewhere they may be classified as drugs or other products.*" would you please suggest us a new way of consuming 300gr of protein or 5gr of creatin per day from food **only** without doubling up which may cost us more money?

Answer (score -1):

Finally I met someone who reads Will Brink! L-Tyrosine in general is good for your well being and is advised by him to take either before or while doing your workouts. It is a non-essential amino acid which can be synthesized by your own body, although having it in excess will only make you pay more.

Don't forget that they are supplements, which in general mean are not necessary but nice to have for the little addition they serve into your diet and progress.

Beta Alanine on the other hand is called "Pump" supplements in jargon. It helps you bit more to reach that one-more-rep and helps your muscles to recuperate better.

Check out [Examine.com](http://examine.com) for further references regarding those supplements (Beta-alanine is already in the first page - which means it is highly sought there). Read with a good eye and don't take every statement for granted. Look for more on [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/) etc.

In general, you get Tyrosine more than enough if you have a well balanced diet (not the nazi bodybuilding diet but an athlete diet). Beta-alanine is a would like to have if you can afford. It also gives nice tingles on your face and body, but more than that, 3 cups of strong coffee or hyphy mud (an invention of Kali) should suffice more than enough for pre-workout purpouses if you don't take them already and are not resistant/intolerant to stimulants.

My advice is, take your whey in isolate form, and use creatine in micronized creapure form. Those are the only (also bro-)scientificaly proven supplements that help you achieve any goals when it comes to building or maintaining muscle and becoming strong.

Comment: Nothing shows that micronized creatine has any benefits compared to normal creatine. It solutes better in water, but that this has any actual benefit on the couldn't been shown.

Comment: See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SqY_JtJazyw. Here is the guru Will Brink-himself in the flesh- telling you where undissolved creatine is wasted money, and on this he shows the difference of dissolving process why micronized creatine is better because it dissoves better and bloats less (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OJvXzP39rg).... I won't reply on this site anymore..

P.S.:Thanks for the downvote though I seriously don't see the reason for the downvote on my reply. a very encouraging way to share your wisdom eh? :S

Comment: I downvoted because you are not answering the question. You don't support your answer with references (and some of your claims really need referencing) instead you tell the OP to do research on his own.

Comment: "...Check out Examine.com for further references regarding those supplements..." this is the very best unbiased reference source for sports- and ergogenics supplements currently available for free to all living beings at the moment. Some of the best of the best people in this area of expertise are the contributors of the content there. I don't understand your remark regarding the lack of reference nor the answer itself. My answer (plus addition) and advise to check it should suffice more than anything imho.

Comment: @lightblue- hahahah, everywhere I go you are damn undervoted buddy. And truth to be told despite the fact that your answers are all over the place and the examples are in the same level of chick gossip magazines, I actually like them and they are more or less informative. I simply couldn't believe the other answer with the most awkward point of view about Supplementation got 3 votes and you're struggling down here. 
I would suggest to dial down your sensational answers and honestly I will vote for them. Specially that 3 cup of coffee. If I have that I won't sleep for a week : ))))